# does not display custom validation error message asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use multiple view control and 2 custom validations the problem is when I click on the next button to next view the error messages in view 1 not display,
 I tried to separate the views into separated pages and the code run successfully but I need to NOT separate the pages I need it altogether due to DB other issues.
what should I do?

this is part of asp.net code
    {

```
<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">

<asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
   <div runat="server" id="Div2"  >
          <div class="divStyle">
    <table  class="auto-style16">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style17">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style1">الايميل<asp:RequiredFieldValidator     ID="RequiredFieldValidator42" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredField"   ForeColor="red" ControlToValidate="TextBox9">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator3" runat="server"   ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" ControlToValidate="TextBox9"   OnServerValidate="CustomValidator3_ServerValidate">*</asp:CustomValidator>
            </td>


     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 

  Text="التالي" style="color:#8fbbbc; font-size:105%; font-weight:bold;" BackColor="white" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="inset" Height="47px" Width="81px" 
     CommandArgument="View2" 
  CommandName="SwitchViewByID" />
```

}

this is the custom validation code
     {

```
   protected void CustomValidator3_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        const string ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=seq;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        string sql2;
        con.Open();
        sql2 = "select Email from applicant where Email = @em";
        SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, con);
        com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@em", TextBox9.Text);
        SqlDataReader rd = com2.ExecuteReader();

        if (rd.HasRows)
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
            Label3.Text = "الايميل مكرر";
        }
        else { args.IsValid = true; }
        rd.Close();
        con.Close();


    }
```

Comment: *"when I click on the next button to next view the error messages in view 1 not display"*; do you want it to display at that moment? It helps if you show us the code.

Comment: yes I want it to display if there is an error but it does not